# Override post-formats in child theme

Tags: child-theme, post-formats, add-theme-support

I'm using a child theme that only has video post format, but parent theme defines all post formats:

`add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'gallery', 'link', 'image', 'quote', 'video', 'audio', 'chat' ) );`

I tried:

`remove_theme_support( 'post-formats' );
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'video' ) );`

But is not working. How can I do this without modifying parent theme?

Answer (score 1):

It's import to set the priority for your `after_setup_theme` higher than your parent theme. The default priority is 10. Using the `twentysixteen` as example, use priority *11* on child themes' `'after_setup_theme'` action. Exemple below:

```
function twentysixteen_child_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array(
        'video',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'twentysixteen_child_setup', 11 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're not just calling these functions within functions.php, but calling them at the right time with add_action().  Try the following:

```
// in your Child Theme's functions.php    

// Use the after_setup_theme hook with a priority of 11 to load after the
// parent theme, which will fire on the default priority of 10
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_post_formats', 11 ); 

function remove_post_formats() {

    remove_theme_support( 'post-formats' );
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'video' ) );
}
```

What's likely happening is that you're attempting to remove theme support before it's even added.